# Python Project not working as I intended it to

Tags: python, pycharm, project

[image: **enter image description here**][image: Beginner Python Project]

Whenever I enter "yes" or "Yes" it prints "get out" and I'm confused because I would think it would print the "Okay let's get started" but it doesn't. Please help.

Comment: "I'm confused because I would think it would print the "Okay let's get started" but it doesn't." Start by explaining why you think it would do so.

Comment: Code, error messages, and data must be tired in, and formatted as code (error messages formatted as quotes).  It's too difficult to read text in pics, and users need to be able to copy-paste for into their editors in order to help. Posts with images of code Are likely to be closed, as it goes against SO'guidelines, as published in the help section. On some devices, and in some apps, is impossible to enlarge images, so such posts become absolutely useless for many viewers.

Answer (score 0):

The input is expected to be **True** if it is a **List**. Therefore, by entering 'yes' or 'Yes' will always give you a **False**

- 'Yes' == ['yes', 'Yes'] -> **False**
- 'yes' == ['yes', 'Yes'] -> **False**

To fix this issue, there are many approaches

**Ex.1**

```
user_input = input()
if user_input.lower() == 'yes':
    print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

**Ex.2**

```
user_input = input()
if user_input in ['yes', 'Yes']:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Personally, I would recommend the first approach because the input can be easily checked and not various.

Comment: @Python No problem. Anyway, it would be great if you could put your code in a code snippet next time instead of using pictures. In this way, you can get help faster and more efficient.

Comment: Got it, I'll do that nextime